# Promtail Stage Camelcase

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

Can anyone help on how to transform incoming JSON text to camelcase in Promtail?

I am thinking of using the `ToLower` function and some kidn of trimming as described in: https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/template/#tolower--toupper

```
{
    "Timestamp": "2022-11-17T07:58:15.6253633Z",
    "Message": "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.",
    "Level": "Error",
    "Exception": "Exception Text"
}
```

Should be

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-11-17T07:58:15.6253633Z",
    "message": "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.",
    "level": "Error",
    "exception": "Exception Text"
}
```

Anyone did something similar or have any advice on how to transform to camelcase?